# what im doing wrong whit this NSDate - Setting up NSDate

Tags: ios, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

im tray to create a firedate to lunch a notification, i get de currente time with

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
```

but i need to compare it with another day setup to for example 06:55 AM,

i've trying using this

```
[NSDateComponets]
```

and

```
int hour=20;  int minute=40; int second=00;

NSDateFormatter *tempFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[tempFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];

NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %02d:%02d:%02d",hour, minute, second];
NSDate *day3 = [tempFormatter dateFromString:message];
```

this says me **(null)**

any help will be apreciate.

Comment: For an hour > 12 you need to use HH, not hh.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `HH` instead of `hh` in DateFormat.

`HH` stands for **24 hour** format.
`hh` stands for **12 hour** format.